# Request header does not include HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN when using AWS JS SDK

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have a Rails application where I can post answers to questions via ajax, it works fine, however, I have added the `aws-js-sdk` script to be able to upload images in my answer from the browser, the image will be uploaded to s3 which sends back the url of the newly uploaded image in a callback, then I save the answer.

I included the library like this :

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "//sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js" %>
```

**Expected behaviour** : when I submit an answer with an image, the request header should include `HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN` to verify the form is submitted from within my website.

**Problem** : request header does not include `HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN`, which is leading to the error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

Comment: I know that I can add          ` = hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token` to add the authenticity token, but I want to know why it's not included automatically.

Comment: Is the S3 upload succeeding? After the S3 upload succeeds, what information about the uploaded image are you submitting along with the form? You aren't showing any of your code so we have to guess at what is wrong, but it seems like you are using the AWS SDK to upload the image, and then doing a standard form submission to your Rails application. The AWS SDK is not involved in the form submission to the Rails application so I'm not sure why you expect it to automatically add headers to that submission.

Comment: @MarkB yes the S3 upload is succeeding, it returns the image url in the s3 bucket, which I include in the body of the answer, then I submit the form to the Rails application. So I am expecting the AWS SDK not to intervene with the form submission, however for some reason it is. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MarkB if I don't upload an image in my answer, the headers DO include the HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN by default, however when do upload an image via AWS SDK, the headers do NOT include HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN.

Comment: Since there is no code I am just assuming that without an image you were able to save the answers but when user uploads an image you are getting this issue. Just wondering are you turning off your authenticity token when you are uploading files to s3 and that is resulting in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The authenticity token is not set in the header. It is set as a hidden field in the form tag, like this:

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_6" action="/users/6/set_facilitator" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="yrr7gWaLmE8ul4s0JcNmAU6H0YB+c7YR/8yCE7it+cRlG9lfdejTSFT7bhydWEQPSqv2E7gVPQ++9mvfJDfJeA==">
  <select class="form-control" data-submit="true" name="user[facilitator_id]" id="user_facilitator_id">
```

When you submit the form via AJAX, the `authenticity_token` is submitted too, as a parameter.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"vcvY+cRQC0oM99l5+BFHu6GShPAedugTP1jRqXCxRa3bVGFLjLSVbMFk78aR5N0ol1WOu1noAo/GF6B67PSk6Q==", ...}
```

I don't know how the S3 gem works, but if it submits directly to Amazon, then it won't use authenticity tokens. Amazon has no way to know the secret key of your rails app on your server. Show us the HTML code that is generated to see if the S3 gem creates a separate form that is outside of your main form, or if it tries to embed a `<form>` within another `<form>`, which is invalid HTML.

If you want, you can turn off token checks in your controller with this line:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :action_method
```

See docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for and here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/security.html#csrf-countermeasures